# Disable link for pseudo :after and :before with pure CSS

Tags: css

```
<a id="nextslide" class="load-item"></a>

#nextslide:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 36px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    border-right: 36px solid transparent;
}
```

If I press the `#nextslide:after` shape, it will load the next slide. I would like to disable link function for the above shape, I want it to work only when I press the `#nextslide` not psuedo. Is there any simple CSS method for this ?

Comment: I think there is not, but you can wrap your `<a>` tag into an other element (like a `<span>` or a `<div>`) and add your style on this parent element. Or you can use an existing parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres is just one possibility with CSS you can add this :

```
#nextslide:after {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

The big problem is compatibility http://caniuse.com/pointer-events